# Docker images versioning for Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment

Tags: jenkins, version-control, docker, continuous-deployment, docker-registry

We're implementing our Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery processes with the use of two well-known concepts: Linux binary packages and `Docker` images.

The most part of the work is already done: we take the code from `GitLab` repo, compile it and put into the `deb` packages stored in `Aptly`, then we create `Docker` images for the every service we have and push the images into the private `Docker Registry` server. Afterwards these images are rolled to the testing environment. Finally we start the services and perform the acceptance testing. This is a continuous process and it starts every time when someone pushes commits to `origin/master`.

[image]

What's still not clear is how to **distinguish stable images** stored in the Docker Registry?

We have to track the state of every image because we need to perform the periodical updates of stable sever. Obviously some releases (i.e. versions of images) will not pass the acceptance tests and must be marked as unusable and filtered out at the every next iteration of Continuous Delivery.

Seems like there's no default implementation of this feature:

1. Default image `repo/tag` is a trivial plain string that cannot hold both version number, build date and QA marks.
2. `Labels` (introduced in [1.6](https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/docker-release-1-6/)) could be a good starting point for a workaround, but we were not able to find the opportunity of relabeling the existing images (note that we need to update the image "metadata" taking into account the results of QA). There is no usable method of querying the image by the label values, but we probably can wrap the Docker API.

So what is the proper way of assigning the versions to the Docker Images? How the QA-related information can be stored? How can we "highlight" the stable image builds? What features of `Jenkins CI` could be used for reaching these purposes? Please share your experience.

**UPD:** after a while I had to start the [discussion](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13928) in Docker issue tracker. Probably someone will find it useful too.

Comment: You should answer your own question with the input gathered on github and accept it. It will definitely help others

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your question is already answered in that discussion link however I would just note that at Bleacher Report we never pushed images to a docker hub (private or hosted) that didn't pass CI first.

- Code pushed
- CircleCI creates a tagged build
- Tests run inside tagged container
- If tests passed CircleCI pushes tagged container to a hub

[Detailed explanation](https://saucelabs.com/blog?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=ci_cd_docker_beanstalk_slack_gantree)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately CircleCI is not the case for us, because it's a cloud solution, but we need to build the pipeline on our own facilities.

Comment: CircleCI can be replaced with Jenkins but I do not have a detailed post for that unfortunately :( however its the same concept, Jenkins listens for git commit triggers then does the building of the docker image, runs it, tests inside it then pushes it to a registry if it passes.